# How can I compile .py to .dll

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll

i have written python function that imports several packages to detect and interps barcode in a pic. and know i want to use this function in C#.
and my question is how can i compile .py to .dll

Comment: Python does not (yet) provide an easy tool to create a dll, however you can do it in C/C++

Answer (score 1):

You can not, at least with CPython (the reference implementation of Python).

However, you may try using [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) — a .NET implementation of Python. It allows your python code to use .NET libraries and vice versa. Note that it only supports Python 2.7.

For more info about different python implementations see https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonImplementations and  https://www.python.org/download/alternatives/

Comment: @MatanHoffman Not sure, I haven't tried it. You can also give [python.net](http://pythonnet.github.io/) a try, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36641708/4510875)

Answer (score 0):

This is never a good idea to make your code import another code from another coding language. The best would be to find a C# library that suits your needs.

Though, I encourage you to look over [IronPython](http://ironpython.net), which is helping inter-languages purposes.