# IronPython Invalid syntax

Tags: python, c#, .net, .net-core, ironpython

I want to integrate Python code with .net. For this I use IronPython. I got the invalid syntax error you see in the title, but the Python code works correctly on its own. I can't understand the problem. I got an error on the `engine.ExecuteFile(source, scope)` line.

This is my C# code:

```cs
var source = @"C:\Users\emreb\Desktop\Sentiment\SentimentAnalysis.py";
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"C:\Python39\Lib");
paths.Add(@"C:\Users\emreb\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages");
paths.Add(@"C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
var scope=engine.CreateScope();
var opeartion = engine.Operations;
engine.ExecuteFile(source, scope);
var Sentiment = scope.GetVariable("SentimentAnalysis");
dynamic instance = opeartion.CreateInstance(Sentiment);
var result = instance.calculate("Bad product");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

and this is my Python code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import flair
class SentimentAnalysis:
  def calculate(text):
    flair_sentiment = flair.models.TextClassifier.load('en-sentiment')


    s = flair.data.Sentence(text)
    flair_sentiment.predict(s)
    total_sentiment = s.labels
    total_sentiment


    tokens = [token.text for token in s.tokens]
    ss = [flair.data.Sentence(s) for s in tokens]
    [flair_sentiment.predict(s) for s in ss]
    sentiments = [s.labels[0].score * (-1,1)[str(s.labels[0]).split()[0].startswith("POS")] for s in ss]
    for sc in sentiments:
      if(sc<0):
        return 0;
    return 1;
```

Comment: Do you get any more information in the error message other than "Syntax error"?  Does the error hint at where the syntax error is in the Python code? If so, please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: I think no problem in python code because it's working properly, You can see what error I got: [https://ibb.co/svGLJxc](https://ibb.co/svGLJxc)

Comment: I note you're using Pandas.  Even if you could get around that 'invalid syntax' error, I believe you'd just hit another roadblock. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36641557/accessing-pandas-library-using-ironpython .